# How to compare the caught exception against standard exceptions in java

Tags: java

How to compare the caught exception against standard exceptions in java?

I mean catching an exception in its general formal (say Exception). and find its more specific form (ArithemeticException) in catch block.

Comment: *"I mean catching an exception in its general formal (say Exception). and find its more speicfic form (ArithemeticException) in catch function."* Why would you do that? Rather than multiple `catch` blocks? (They're not functions.)

Comment: to do certain opertion which is common to all exception but differ a little in them. I felt rather than copy all thoes coding to each exceptions catch block work in single catch block itself.

Comment: I'd do it by factoring that logic into a function and then calling that function as necessary from `catch` blocks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `instanceof`

```
   if( Exception instanceof ArithemeticException) {
     // yes this is a type ArithemeticException
   }
```

That tells you the type at runtime.

Apart from this, a standard solution will be (someone just commented), `catching more specific exception.`

```
catch(ArithemeticException ae) {

}
catch(Exception ae) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using instance of ,you can always use `Object.getclass()`

```
catch(Exception ae) {

    if (ae.getClass() == java.lang.ArithmeticException.class){
    //Its an ArithmeticException
    }

    if(ae instanceof java.io.IOException){

    //Its an IOException
        }

}
```